# How to troubleshoot errors INSERT INTO in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO aa_Tanks_Ponds ([User_Name],
                            [Type],
                            Site_Name,
                            Species,
                            Year_Class,
                            Tank_Pond,
                            Letter,
                            [Name],
                            Tank_Pond_uID,
                            Start_Inventory_#,
                            Start_Inventory_lbs,
                            Start_Inventory_avg,
                            Stocking_#,
                            Stocking_lbs,
                            Stocking_from,
                            Stocking_Total_#,
                            Stocking_Total_lbs,
                            Sales_#,
                            Sales_lbs,
                            Sales_Total_#,
                            Sales_Total_lbs,
                            Mortality_#,
                            Mortality_lbs,
                            Transfers_#,
                            Transfers_lbs,
                            Transfers_To,
                            Transfer_Total_#,
                            Transfer_Total_lbs,
                            Plus_Min_#,
                            Plus_Min_lbs,
                            Plus_Min_Total_#,
                            Plus_Min_Total_lbs,
                            Feed_lbs_Tanks_Ponds,
                            Feed_growth_feed,
                            Feed_growth_FCR,
                            Feed_growth_gain,
                            Final_Inventory_#,
                            Final_Inventory_lbs,
                            Final_Inventory_avg,
                            bg_color,
                            tx_color,
                            sort_order,
                            FeedValue)
VALUES ('Chase Ayers','Chase Ayers','Chase Ayers','Chase Ayers','Chase Ayers','Chase Ayers'),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL),
       ('Dry Creek','Dry Creek','Dry Creek','Dry Creek','Dry Creek','Dry Creek'),
       ('Sturgeon','Sturgeon','Sturgeon','Sturgeon','Sturgeon','Sturgeon'),
       ('14C','14C','14C','14C','14C','14C'),
       ('Tank','Tank','Tank','Tank','Tank','Tank'),
       ('H','H','H','H','H','H'),
       ('H1','H2','H3','H4','H5','H6'),
       ('DCH1','DCH2','DCH3','DCH4','DCH5','DCH6'),
       (2985,2995,2678,2947,3175,3040),
       (30144,27560,27161,27956,32600,33221),
       (10.1,9.2,10.14,9.49,10.27,10.93),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (2,2,2,2,2,2),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (2985,2995,2678,2947,3175,3040),
       (30144,27560,27161,27956,32600,33221),
       (10.1,9.2,10.14,9.49,10.27,10.93),
       ('FFFF00','99CC33','3399CC','FF66CC','FFFF00','FFFF00'),
       ('996600','CCFF66','660099','CCCCCC','900000','FFCC99'),
       (0,0,0,0,0,0),
       (NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I have checked through it multiple time to try and find why it says the error:

> There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified
>   in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must
>   match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement.

To me this error is saying that I have 43 statements in the `INSERT` Clause, and I don't have 43 statements in the `VALUES` Clause.  Yet every time I check through there is a match.

Is there an easier way to trouble shoot data like this other than just walking through it manually?

Comment: I didn't bother counting all of them, but `(NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)` is definitely less values than columns you mention.

Comment: You're trying to insert into 42 columns but all of your VALUES have only about 7 items.

Comment: Your table valued constructor has a different number of values on nearly every row. And none of them have as many as the columns you have in the insert statement. Then you have mismatched datatypes all over the place also.

Comment: The error is that each *row* being inserted should have 43 columns.  You seem to have the data transposed.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, Do u want to insert multiple values  into all columns ?

Comment: Your table has 43 columns. All  of your data is pivoted so you are trying to insert each row into a single column (vertically). You need to pivot the data so you have 1 data point in each VALUES row for each column (43 comma separated parameters, 6 total enclosing parenthesis)

Comment: @GordonLinoff well spotted. I was thinking the same thing and apparently you already figured that out. :)

Comment: Yes, It looks as though I missed that it should be:
INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3)
VALUES (col1,col2,col3),(col1,col2,col3),etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have in the brackets after the "VALUES" is what is trying to be inserted. So currently you're trying to insert 6 lots of "Chase Ayers" into 43 rows. Your first line of the insert would be this (then just needs adjusting for the remaining 5 rows to be inserted) - Notice all the values to be inserted are within 1 set of brackets:

```
INSERT INTO aa_Tanks_Ponds ([User_Name],[Type],Site_Name,Species,Year_Class,Tank_Pond,Letter,[Name],Tank_Pond_uID,Start_Inventory_#,Start_Inventory_lbs,Start_Inventory_avg,Stocking_#,Stocking_lbs,Stocking_from,Stocking_Total_#,Stocking_Total_lbs,Sales_#,Sales_lbs,Sales_Total_#,Sales_Total_lbs,Mortality_#,Mortality_lbs,Transfers_#,Transfers_lbs,Transfers_To,Transfer_Total_#,Transfer_Total_lbs,Plus_Min_#,Plus_Min_lbs,Plus_Min_Total_#,Plus_Min_Total_lbs,Feed_lbs_Tanks_Ponds,Feed_growth_feed,Feed_growth_FCR,Feed_growth_gain,Final_Inventory_#,Final_Inventory_lbs,Final_Inventory_avg,bg_color,tx_color,sort_order,FeedValue)
VALUES ('Chase Ayers',NULL,'Dry Creek','Sturgeon','14C','Tank','H','H1','DCH1',2985,30144,10.1,0,0,' ',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,' ',0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2985,30144,10.1,'FFFF00','996600',0,NULL);
```

Comment: This doesn't ***demonstrate*** that `INSERT INTO table (x, y, z) VALUES (11, 12, 13), (21, 22, 23), (31, 32, 33)` works perfectly well for inserting three rows.  *(It only kind of implies it...)*

Answer (score 2):

I think you're expecting that each group of `()` is a column of values. Those are rows. Each Item in that group is a column.

You need to insert one row at a time.

```
VALUES(User_Name
,Type
,Site_Name
,Species
,Year_Class
,Tank_Pond
,Letter
,NAME
,Tank_Pond_uID
,...etc)
,
(User_Name
,Type
,Site_Name
,Species
,Year_Class
,Tank_Pond
,Letter
,NAME
,Tank_Pond_uID
,...etc)
```

This makes sense because data are stored as rows in the database. They are not stored as columns thus (basically) every operation is a row based operation.

Comment: Even if the table is a column-store the syntax is still row based.  It's not a consequence of the storage, it's just the syntax...

Answer (score 1):

> In the SQL Server Management Studio, errors can be tracked down easily, using the built in Error List pane. This pane can be activated in the View menu, or by using shortcuts **Ctrl+\ and Ctrl+E**

Read more [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-syntax-errors/).

Comment: Perfect this is going to help so much in the long run thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because it's much more legible, you might consider putting the to-be-imported data into a CSV and then importing *that* to SQL, rather than having to write this out in the current format. It's easier to be sure that everything is arranged as you want it to be. Here's the how-to on CSV import, assuming you're using the SQL Server Management Studio: https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx